# Docker service crash when firewall is stopped or started

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, firewalld

I have two machines and I make a docker swarm cluster with them, then I created a service with 5 replicas to verify that the load balancer is working good but I noticed the firewall was blocking the two machines so I added the required ports:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=2377/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=7946/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=7946/udp --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=4789/tcp --permanent
```

Everything is working good, my only doubt is when the firewall is stopped or started then docker stop working and I don't know why this happen?

Can someone explain me the behavior of this? Is it possible to avoid this behavior or this is a normal behavior?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you see if firewall rules are still there?

Comment: Yes the rules are there, if I run `firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all` it shows  `ports: 7946/tcp 4789/udp 2377/tcp 7946/udp`

Comment: Better open a issue at https://github.com/moby/moby